# How to set up a new Blazor ServerApp on a Linux machine running NGINX and get data from a MSSQL Windows-Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, nginx, web-applications, blazor

We are trying to build an Intranet Web based App with Blazor Server and use follwing systems

- Blazor Server App with VisualStudio 2022
- .NET 7.0
- nginx v1.18.0 on a Debian 11.6 with IP `192.168.123.230`
- Microsoft SQL 2014 Express on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with IP `192.168.123.4`, hostname `powdersql01` and Database called `powder`; we also created an user called `blazor`

---

We managed to create a Blazor site with a ConnectionString to the SQL Server and it works fine when we start it within VisualStudio 2022.

ConnectionString:

```
Data Source=powdersql01\\POWSQL;Initial Catalog=powder;User ID=blazor;Password=password;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

When deploying on our nginx Server the basic site without content from the SQL Server works also well but as soon as we click on the `/getSQLdata`-Hyperlink we get following error on the nginx Server while running the `sudo dotnet /var/www/test1.mydomain.local/BlazorAppNoAuth.dll`:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Connection String 'PowderConnection' not found
      System.InvalidOperationException: Connection String 'PowderConnection' not found
         at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Main>$>b__0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in \\myfiles\powder\software\Testprojekt\BlazorTest\BlazorAppNoAuth\BlazorAppNoAuth\Program.cs:line 10
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider _, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateInitializer>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.PerformPropertyInjection(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent instance)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame& frame, Int32 parentComponentId)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit '_GgDwy1Z8r0AFqW1T6TWKLbka1iN8UxQkRZo-0gGYls'.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Connection String 'PowderConnection' not found
         at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Main>$>b__0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in \\myfiles\powder\software\Testprojekt\BlazorTest\BlazorAppNoAuth\BlazorAppNoAuth\Program.cs:line 10
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider _, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateInitializer>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.PerformPropertyInjection(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent instance)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame& frame, Int32 parentComponentId)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

---

Our nginx config files are as follow:

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        #Blazor
  map $http_connection $connection_upgrade {
    "~*Upgrade" $http_connection;
    default keep-alive;}

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test1.mydomain.local *.test1.mydomain.local;

    # Configure the SignalR Endpoint
    location / {
      # App server url
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;

      # Configuration for WebSockets
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_cache off;
      # WebSockets were implemented after http/1.0
      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      # Configuration for ServerSentEvents
      # proxy_buffering off;

      # Configuration for LongPolling or if your KeepAliveInterval is longer than 60 seconds
      proxy_read_timeout 100s;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }


        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/test1.mydomain.local.conf`:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name test1.mydomain.local;

       location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       }
}
```

BTW the CSS is on the nginx also not working.

- We tried to get a connection with the `blazor` user by creating a udl-File and it worked.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

---

We guess the problem is that the content root path is set to `/home/johndoe` instead of `var/www/test1.mydomain.local`
as seen in the log while running `sudo dotnet /var/www/test1.mydomain.local/BlazorAppNoAuth.dll`:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/johndoe
```

How do we change the `content root path`?

Comment: I would start by addressing the error `Unhandled exception rendering component: Connection String 'PowderConnection' not found`. This is keeping the Blazor process from correctly starting and allowing it to serve content.

Comment: What does your `appsettings.json` file look like? (In particular the connection strings section.) Note that JSON property names (aka. keys) are case-sensitive. Also when you deploy to Linux/Unix systems they generally have case-sensitive file systems so a `AppSettings.json` would be ignored when .NET is trying to load `appsettings.json`.

Comment: Aside... this is probably not your issue, but choose one authentication method. `Integrated Security=True;` means to use the Windows authentication token of the current process (or the Kerberos authenticaton token on Linux/Unix systems), whereas `User ID=blazor;Password=password;` means to use SQL Login authentication.

Comment: The problem seems that the content root path is set to `/home/johndoe` instead of `var/wwwroot`
see
`info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/johndoe`
but how do i change the content root path? in a nginx config or in VisualStudio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying we found the solution:

in `Program.cs` we added the following lines to set the `content root path`:

```
WebApplicationOptions options = new WebApplicationOptions {
    ContentRootPath = "/var/www/test1.mydomain.local"
};
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
```